# How can I refuse a dinner with my relatives?

Tags: conflict-aversion, family, saying-no, parents

I have never been close to one of my relatives. The only living thing I like is my dog.

We are having dinner tomorrow with a bunch of relatives and friends. My dad will pick me up at 7 pm but I don't want to go there.

The issue is all of my relatives believe that it is necessary for a person to be socialized and adopt the habits of most people. I don't want to adopt those habits because I like myself just the way I am. Also, my parents abused me when I was a little kid; both of my parents used to insult and beat me and they forced me to join their company.

**How should I put it nicely that I don't want to join them at the relatives' dinner?** I am trying not to lose my calm and argue with them one more time.

Comment: As written this looks like a phrasing request. What's wrong with just telling them that you don't want to join them for dinner?

Comment: Hi Warrior! As sphennings pointed out, it's a bit unclear why you could not "simply" refuse having dinner with them. Could you please edit your post and tell us whether you've tried it before (and it didn't work) or why you think that simply telling them wouldn't work? That way, this wouldn't be a phrasing request and we may be able to help you more easily. Thanks!

Comment: What is the cultural background of your family? Do you mean their actual business, when you say that your parents forced you "to join their company" or do you mean something else by that (e.g. social group, organization etc.)? Also, depending on your parents' character it may be impossible to refuse anything they want you to do (or not to do) without confrontation/conflict.

Comment: One time I refused they informed the police I was missing and I got in real trouble.

Comment: When I say company I mean social gathering.

Comment: If you're over the age of independence, I don't see why you would be held accountable for your parents actions (falsely calling the police). Also - it sounds like you've already gone past the 'polite refusal' stage...

Comment: @Warrior, like some comments mentioned above, you could add country/cultural background and age to be able to provide a more appropriate/accurate response.